# What is the difference between a lib and an module with autoconf

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries, autoconf

I have to check that certain libraries (libm, libdl) are present in order to compile my library.

In my configure.ac template file, there is `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` macros and `PKG_CHECK_LIB` macros.

I don't understand which one to use and how?

The `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` seems the most global one because it checks if a whole library is present and `PKG_CHECK_LIB` checks only if one function is accessible… But when I do `PKG_CHECK_MODULES([LIBM],[libm],[],[exit -1])`, it exists and I don't understand why.

I think I'm misunderstanding some concepts. Maybe someone could lead me to good references.

Comment: There's no such a thing as `PKG_CHECK_LIB`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PKG_CHECK_MODULES` is for integrating with packages that have [pkg-config](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/) metadata.  This metadata is typically stored in a file called `foo.pc` (for package `foo`) in someplace like `/usr/share/pkgconfig`.  This file will say where `foo` and its associated files (header files, libraries, executables, data, etc.) have actually been installed.

However, most packages don't use the `pkg-config` system, including the standard C library which is where `libm` and `libdl` are.  So you'll need to test for them using `AC_CHECK_LIB`.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused, so I'll go on a bit of a tangent here:

---

Once upon a time, there was X11; there were many incompatible installations of X11. To write code that would compile against each variant, people would write crazy autoconf macros to try to figure out automatically what libraries to list before, what libraries to list after, and what extra flags were needed in between. (see `AC_PATH_X`, `AC_PATH_XTRA`).

Some people tried more sensible approaches, and wrote shell scripts to install along the libraries; so you would just call them and they would give you all the magic flags needed for that specific libraries. (see `sdl-config`, `wx-config`, `freetype-config`, `motif-config`, etc)

Then the folks from freedesktop.org decided it was a chore for everyone to maintain those scripts that did essentially the same thing, so they wrote a tool (pkg-config) that would work like all those `*-config` scripts, and would not require a shell to run (yay for Windows users). All the library authors need to do is to write the metadata in the `*.pc` files, and install them along the libraries.

---

Regarding autoconf, it has low-level ways to poke around the system to find out about the libraries: `AC_CHECK_HEADERS`, to see if the headers are present and usable, and `AC_CHECK_LIB`, to see if it's possible to link against them.

The pkg-config tool comes with convenience macros for autoconf, mainly `PKG_CHECK_MODULES`, which instead of poking around, it simply looks for the metadata the library might have installed.

---

Regarding libm, libdl, as ldav1s said, they are part of the system; some systems need explicit link against libm (which provides math functions) and/or libdl (which provides functions for dynamically loading shared objects). Often other tools, like gcc or libtool, take care of linking against them. Unfortunately they don't come with meta-data for pkg-config, so if you have to find them manually, you'll have to poke around with the old `AC_CHECK_HEADERS` and `AC_CHECK_LIB` macros to find them.